# msmtp logging doesn't work in /var/log/mail/[logfile].log

Tags: permissions, email, mail, apparmor, logging

Good day

I'm using msmtp to send mails. I have different accounts that log to different logfiles. Unfortunately whenever it tries to log the following error appears:

send-mail: cannot log to /var/log/mail/[logfile].log: cannot open: Permission denied

I tried the following:

- change owner/group of the file
- tried 777 on the logfiles
- edited the file as the user running the command (which worked)
- disabled apparmor

Nothing has worked so far. I've run out of ideas... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Classically you would set the location and name of the logfile in ~/.msmtprc, in a location that you have write access to and make sure the whole ~/.msmtprc file has the appropriate permission: `chmod 600 ~/.msmtprc`. Do you really need the log file away from $HOME?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ideally I would like to have seperate logfiles because of the system we have set up with different clients. I know that the rights are ok, especially since I also tried 777.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was still the apparmor. I didn't restart the server and so it didn't work as expected. I followed the instructions found here and excluded msmtp from apparmor. This solved the problem.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-apparmor-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux